# How can I create a dummy using factor() with the mtcars data?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I get the message:

> Error in factor(carb) : Object 'carb' not found.

But it should find carb, because it is in the data.

I can create a factor for "am" using

`mtcars$amf <- factor(mtcars$am, labels=c("automatic", "manual"))`

Import data:

`data(mtcars)`

Define factor variable:

`mtcars$carbf <- factor(carb)`

Then I get the error message:

> Error in factor(carb) : Object 'carb' not found.

What I expect is that a categorical variable is automatically included as a set of dummy variables if it is defined as factor variable.

So when I would run

`lm(mpg~wt+carbf, data=mtcars)`

it would get me a output with dummy variables?

Comment: Did you just forgot the dataframe name ? `mtcars$carbf <- factor(mtcars$carb)`

Answer (score 1):

`carb` doesn't exist in the global environment, only in the context of the data frame. Because of that you need to reference explicitly.

See below:

```
mtcars$carbf <- factor(mtcars$carb)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way i could add carb into groups? So carb 1&2 are one column in the output? Or that carb are columns and the mt effect is split up for each column?